# Set specific date and time as reminder in Outlook for an appointment

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, reminder, appointments

How to set a specific reminder time, say Oct 21 2013 11:33 AM, for an appointment in MS Outlook 2010, which is scheduled for some different / arbitrary date?

Certainly, I could just schedule the appointment to 11:43 AM and set a 10 minute reminder, but I want to keep the correct appointment date & time, e.g. Oct 23 2013 13:30.

When I create a task, it is possible to set the date and time as desired, but for apppointments it seems to me I can only choose the amount of time which I want to be reminded in advance and to be reminded at specific time, I would need to calculate this amount of time, which is annoying.